# Ansible 'find' command - print only filenames

Tags: module, ansible, find

I am trying to use Ansible find command to delete files with a given pattern.  Before executing the delete part, I want to list the files that will be deleted.  I want to list only filenames including path.   The default debug prints a lot of information

```
- name: Ansible delete old files from pathslist
  find:
    paths: "{{ pathslist }}"
    patterns:
    - "authlog.*"
    - "server.log.*"
  register: var_log_files_to_delete

- name : get the complete path
  set_fact:
    files_found_path: "{{ var_log_files_to_delete.files }}"

- debug:
    var: files_found_path
```

This outputs like below

```
{
        "atime": 1607759761.7751443,
        "ctime": 1615192802.0948966,
        "dev": 66308,
        "gid": 0,
        "gr_name": "root",
        "inode": 158570,
        "isblk": false,
        "ischr": false,
        "isdir": false,
        "isfifo": false,
        "isgid": false,
        "islnk": false,
        "isreg": true,
        "issock": false,
        "isuid": false,
        "mode": "0640",
        "mtime": 1607675101.0750349,
        "nlink": 1,
        "path": "/var/log/authlog.87",
        "pw_name": "root",
        "rgrp": true,
        "roth": false,
        "rusr": true,
        "size": 335501,
        "uid": 0,
        "wgrp": false,
        "woth": false,
        "wusr": true,
        "xgrp": false,
        "xoth": false,
        "xusr": false
}
```

I tried `files_found_path: "{{ var_log_files_to_delete.files['path'] }}"`  but it generates an error.

How can I print only the paths?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Jinja2 filter `map` as a parameter `attribute` to transform a list of dict into a list of a specific attribute of each element (https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#map):

```yaml
- name : get the complete path
  set_fact:
    files_found_path: "{{ var_log_files_to_delete.files | map(attribute='path') | list }}"
```

For more complex data extraction, there is the `json_query` filter (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-json-data-json-queries)